# Angular 5 synchronous HTTP call

Tags: angular, http, promise, observable

I have an Angular 5 application in which I have to call some heavy REST service (usually takes some seconds). I need its result in different part of application, so I would like to store the result in a DataStorageService.
Basically, this is I would like to achieve:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataStorageService {

private result: MyCustomObject;

constructor(private service: Service) {}

getResult(): MyCustomObject {
    if (typeof this.result === 'undefined') {
        // save result
    }
    return result;
}
```

The question is how I can wait until HTTP request is finished and then save and return the 'result' object. I tried to solve it using Promise and Observable as well, but none of them worked fine.

1. Observable:

   ```
   if (typeof this.result === 'undefined') {
       this.service.call()
           .subscribe(response => this.result = response);
   }
   return this.result;  // wait for save and return MyCustomObject
   ```
2. Promise:

   ```
   if (typeof this.result === 'undefined') {
       this.service.call()
           .toPromise()
           .then(response => this.result = response);
   }
   return this.result;  // wait for save and return MyCustomObject
   ```

Comment: Your `getResult(): Promise<MyCustomObject>` should also return a promise/observable. Will code the missing codes, when returning from lunch. In the meantime look into https://github.com/ngrx/store might bring a new solution to the problem.

Comment: I would like to avoid returning a Promise or Observable. I need to aggregate the result into different objects according to opened page. This would make my code so ugly if I always have to subscribe to a Promise. Instead of using a simple Object.

Comment: Note about code clarity and maintenance: Your method is named `getResult()`, but it actually save the result, so the behavior does not match the name and that leads to confusion

Comment: You're right David. I wrote it from scratch for a better understanding. Maybe it worth to move the save function into an ngOnInit method.

Comment: I updated my question because the original one was too ambiguous with unnecessary codes. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try using `await/async`

```
async getResult(): Promise<MyCustomObject> {
    if (typeof this.result === 'undefined') 
    {
        // save result
        this.result = await this.service.call()
        .toPromise()
        .then(resp =>resp as MyCustomObject);//Do you own cast here

    }
    return this.result;
}
```

Comment: should not the method signature be: async getResult(): Promise<MyCustomObject> ?

Comment: Why are this answer accepted as correct? this is not synchronous, this is just using async/await instead promises. 
Sync request must be supported by the http library and must mark The underlay xmlHtppRequest as synchrnous. The question is probably wrong though. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests.

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted the response of David above, but I think there may be a design flaw. You should actually not save (in local storage) the result in the `getResult` function. It's a side effect and it might be undesirable at some point and render your `getResult` hardly reusable in case you just want to get without save.

Also having the `this.result === 'undefined'` might create problem as well if you want to refresh the data.

So if you want to get these results in the `ngOnInit`, you could do it like that:

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (typeof this.result === 'undefined') {
        this.getResult().then(result => {
            // save the result here
            this.result = result;

            // save in local storage ...
        });
    }
}

getResult(): Promise<MyCustomObject> {
    return this.service.call().toPromise();
}
```

Note that you cannot await in `ngOnInit`. But now your `getResult()` function is reusable in many other cases.

Comment: This was actually mentioned in the comments of the OP by David Votrubec.

Answer (score -1):

**The question is how I can wait until HTTP request is finished and then save and return the 're
sult' object.**

// Code in service:

```
ServiceMethod:Observabke<any>(){
     if (typeof this.result === 'undefined') {
                return this.service.call().map(res=>res);
}
```

// This is code in component.

```
 componentMethod(){


        return this.service.ServiceMethod()
            .subscribe(response => {
                this.result = response;
               },
               ()=>//handle error,
               () => // call completed { return this.result;  // Subscriber});
    }
    return this.weeklyPlayer;  // MyCustomObject (This return won't wait for http to get completed. Not sure why you want multiple returns.)

    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I guess it's because your code does not wait for the http call to finish to assign and return the value

Comment: If you are talking about "return this.weekPlayer" I have added in comment that it wont work. And for this result, It is assigned in subsrcibe and returned when call is completed.

Comment: I didn't downvote it. Anyway, I already tried something very similar. If I call this method from a component, it also returns with a Subscriber instead of MyCustomObject. As far as I understand, I must use Promise with await/async to wait for service response. It's not possible to solve my problem with Observable.

Comment: Oh wait. If you want to call it from component, its other way. I am updating my answer.

Comment: Thank you Dheeraj, I really appreciate your help. Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think it's solvable with Observable in any way. If I call "getResult()" in a component it always returns with a Subscriber instead of my real object. The only solution which worked if I mapped Observable to Promise and used await/async keywords to pause the execution and wait for the resolution.