# How to make typescript execute code seqentially?

Tags: angular, typescript

my code seems like it doesn't wait for executing some of the code and goes further.

```
isAdmin(): boolean {
    this.getLoggedUser();
    this.getRole();
    console.log(this.admin);
    console.log('isAdmin');
    return this.admin;
  }

  getRole() {
    this.httpClient.get<boolean>('/api/has-role-admin').
    subscribe((data) => {
    this.admin = data;
    console.log(this.admin);
    console.log('getRole');
    }
    );
 }
```

Console result:

```
false
isAdmin
true
getRole
```

I want to finish getRole() method and after that step to the rest in isAdmin(). How could I receive that behaviour?

Comment: don't `subscribe`. something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49444816/1132334

Comment: Also, keep in mind `console.log` is asynchronous.in some browsers.

Comment: Thanks for advice, this time console.log is correct :) But another problem is when I create isAdmin() as async, how to make it still return boolean?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is aynchronous because you subscribe to an observable:

```
isAdmin(): boolean {
    this.getLoggedUser();
    this.getRole();
    console.log(this.admin);
    console.log('isAdmin');
    return this.admin;
  }

  getRole() {
    this.httpClient.get<boolean>('/api/has-role-admin').
    subscribe((data) => {
    ------------------------------------- This block will complete after the method returns
      this.admin = data;
      console.log(this.admin);
      console.log('getRole');
    }
    );
}
```

If your code involves observables, it cannot be sequential by definition. You need to refactor your methods in order to use the observable and not depend upon the side of effects of what is in the subscribe method.

I would refactor your code this way (I made several assumptions about your code, however, the general idea should hold):

```
public interface UserInfo{
    public isAdmin: boolean = false;
}

public getUserInfo(userId: integer): Observable<UserInfo> {
    let params = new HttpParams()
        .append('userId', userId.toString());

    return this.http.get<UserInfo>(this.baseUrl + "api/has-role-admin", { params: params });
}

public isAdminUser(userId: number): Observable<boolean>(){
    return this.getUserInfo(userId).pipe(map(x=> { return x.isAdmin; }));
}
```

and the server side api should return `UserInfo`. you can call `isAdminUser(this.getLoggedUser().userId`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in a controller?  A method named `isAdmin` should probably not be making an HTTP call, especially if it is called by your template because then you will end up making the HTTP call many times over.

Instead, write an `ngOnInit` where you make the call and store the result into an instance variable on the component.

Also, HTTP calls take time, and you should never block the thread in Javascript.  So that HTTP call generates an `Observable` that you subscribe to.  The subscription happens instantly but the callback won't be executed until the HTTP response arrives.

Two common patterns to deal with this are to hide the element with an `ngIf` until it has been loaded or to use the `async` pipe.